# Manually setting focus to a <lockup> element in TVJS

Tags: javascript, tvos, apple-tv, tvjs

I can't find any method in the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSFrameworkReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016076) to manually set the focus to an element.
It is supposed to support the `DOM Element` class, but when i do

```
var elem = ele.ownerDocument.getElementById("start");
elem.focus();
```

it does nothing. `elem` is correctly set, but it doesn't recognize the `focus()` method.

Comment: which element it is (with `id` #start)?

Comment: @Paritosh it's a `lockup` element. It should be eligible for highlighting

Comment: What is the `elem.ownerDocument` object?

Comment: @MaximGoncharuk an IKDOMElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple's TVJS Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSFrameworkReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016076) doesn't provide any method in his classes to manually focus an element.

Neither in the standard Document Object Module classes it incorporates have any kind of method to directly access the DOM and focus an element.

The closes thing available is the [`autoHighlight` attribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/TVJSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH42-SW1) which allows to focus on render some specific elements in certain positions.

Answer (score 0):

In pure js you can `document.getElementById("start").autofocus;` : On page load input is autofocus

Comment: I already use the TVML approach for that, setting the `autoHighlight` attribute to `true`. The problem is setting the focus after an event.

Comment: Okay! 
Your proposition is right in js `document.getElementById("start").focus()`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

Comment: Problem is I have no direct access to `document` object. Neither to methods such as `focus()`

Answer (score -1):

Use [autoHighlight](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/TVJSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH42-SW5) for this purpose.

> autoHightlight="true"

Both the containing element and one child element have to be set to true.