# How to set buttonLockup highlighted in TVML or TVJS?

Tags: focus, highlight, tvos, tvml, tvjs

In `compilationTemplate` it's possible to put `buttonLockup` under `heroImg`. I would like to make this button highlighted when view appear on screen.

I have only one button there. It doesn't matter if this will be done with JS or XML, I just want to make it work.

I've read this thread [Manually setting focus to a <lockup> element in TVJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063246/), and none of the solutions work for me.

`IKDOMElement` representing `buttonLockup` does not have:

- `autohightlight` property or method
- `autofocus` property or method
- `highlight` property or method
- `focus` property or method
- setting `autoHighlight` attribute `buttonLockup` tag does nothing

If anyone would like to play around and check this, you can use Apple sample app from here: https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/samplecode/TVMLCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html Template name: `Compilation.xml.js`, there are three buttons, highlight any of them when view appear on screen.

Answer (score 0):

What I have learned so far is that everything that isn't in the [Apple TVML documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/TVJSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH42-SW1) specifically written it's not implemented and won't work (and sadly, there is a big chance it won't be in the future).

According to the previous statement, these are the elements you can put in the `compilationTemplate` that are eligible for the `autoHighlight` attribute:

- compilationTemplate that contains listItemLockup elements
- row that contains any focusable element

I tried to put some focusable elements under the `row` inside `itemBanner` and none of them renders the `autoHighligh` attribute correctly, neither dies the `listItemLockup`inside the row, which should be focusable according to the documentation, so I am guessing that the `itemBanner` itself (or the `relatedContent`) which does not accept the attribute.

My recommendation is you try to find another template that suits better what you are trying to achieve. In this case `listItemTemplate` in the very same TVMLCatalog example seems pretty similar to the `compilationTemplate`